# Default Django Rest Framework HTML POST Forms not showing after upgrading to latest versions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Previously when using the Django REST Framework I got browsable API endpoints, and I could enter data with POST and PUT forms.

However, after I recently updated my dependencies the HTML form for POST and PUT doesn't show up anymore [picture 2], and even trying to click my user name in the top right to get options to for example log out, I'm simply redirected back to the same url with /# appended to it [picture 1].
If I go to a specific entry by entering `localhost/myEndpoint/1/` and I try the DELETE button, that does not do anything either.

There are no logs indicating something went wrong in the output of `manage.py runserver`

Is this a bug or is there some way that I can fix this?

I was using an updated to the following versions:

- Django 2.2 => 2.2.9
- djangorestframework 3.9.2 => 3.11.0
- djangorestframework-simplejwt => 4.4.0

**Picture 1:**
[image]

**Picture 2:**
[image]

Comment: Did you resolve the issue ? I can't also make post/put/patch/delete request. When I click on the button it just send get request instead of the corresponding header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect static after upgrading.

Comment: What do you mean by collecting the static ? Do I have to change something to the static file of DRF to make it work ?

Comment: It's something about django updating how they use static files, CSS or something or some javascript link formatting, idk. You just have to collect static again and replace the old version. `./manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are inheriting your Serializer class from `serializers.Serializer`, use `serializers.ModelSerializer` instead and this should fix the issue

that is,

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): # instead of serializers.Serializer
    # your class definition here
    pass
```

This should fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after a lot of research I found the issue was with ublock origin.

Ublock origin was preventing the browser from making request on localhost so I deactivated it and now it work as expected.

Check your adblocker if you have the same issue.